# Error: redirect_uri_mistmatch after get Bundle configured and try to login using Github application

Tags: symfony, github, hwioauthbundle

I'm using [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) Symfony2 Bundle and I follow the steps on [this guide](http://m2mdas.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/integrate-hwioauthbundle-with-fosuserbundle/) to get the Bundle configured and working but I get this error:

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch
error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application
```

How I fix this?

**Extra info**

`hwioauth.yml` (included in config.yml)

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: secure
    connect:
        confirmation: true
    resource_owners:
        github:
            type:                github
            client_id:           "%github_app_id%"
            client_secret:       "%github_app_secret%"
            scope:               "user:email"
    fosub:
            # try 30 times to check if a username is available (foo, foo1, foo2 etc)
            username_iterations: 30

            # mapping between resource owners (see below) and properties
            properties:
                github: githubID
```

Routes at `routing.yml`

```
#HWIOAuthBundle
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /secure/connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /secure/connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /secure/connect

hwi_github_login:
    prefix: /secure/check-github
```

HWIOAuth part at `security.yml`

```
secure:
        pattern: ^/secure
        oauth:
            failure_path: /secure/connect
            login_path: /secure/connect
            check_path: /secure/connect
            provider: fos_userbundle
            resource_owners:
                github: "/secure/check-github"
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge

        anonymous:    true
        logout:
            path:           /secure/logout
            target:         /secure/connect #where to go after logout

access_control:
    - { path: ^/secure/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secure/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secure, roles: ROLE_USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this link [HwiOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle). Please specify the redirect URI properly while creating app for the network.

If you used facebook: No need to mention the redirect URI. While working with google we have to specify the redirect URI properly.

Please follow [HwiOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)  documentation and let me know If you found any error.

Comment: I added extra info to main post and also check [Github docs for Redirect URI](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls) (the provider I'm using for testing) and this aren't required, why the error so?

Comment: Once check your call back url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this post if it can help someone:

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/532

I didn't selected the right url as callback in the Github app. It must be /login/check-github if we follow the documentation.